# Is "To [Adverb] [Infinitive]" Still a Valid Infinitive form?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, adverbs, infinitives, adverb-position

This question is specifically for **I work `to nearly get` success**, but the question is also asking in general.

I shouldn't use nearly to get because that would detract from from my purpose of working.

Comment: @rjpond Does that mean that I should delete this post?

Comment: Not sure.  Do the answers on the page I linked to (and the one that's been added below) answer your question to your satisfaction?  If not, edit your question and give as much detail as possible about which point you're unclear about.

Comment: @rjpond Yes, that answers it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a 'split infinitive', and it is a useful way to associate the adverb with the infinite verb 'get' (rather than the habitual finite verb 'work').  The un-split "to get nearly" sounds bad, and it tempts the listener to associate the adverb with 'success'.